# regarding passed id to save data in the database using symfony framework

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

im new to symfony framework i make a jquery ajax form here it runs well it also saves the images to the uploads folder my problem here is it will not save to database the filename. how do i passed the id im not using the symfony form.
Here is my code in indexSuccess.php

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loading").hide();
        $('#send_form').ajaxForm({  
            target: '.result',
            beforeSubmit: validate,
            success: function(data) {
              $(".result").html(data);
              $(".result").show();
            }      
        }); 

    });

      function validate(){ 
        var photoValue = $('input[name=files]').fieldValue();  
        if (!photoValue[0]){ 
            alert('Please upload a picture of you.'); 
            return false;
        }    
      }

    </script>

    <div id="sf_admin_content">
      <h2>Company Gallery</h2>
      <br />
      <form id="send_form" action="<?php echo url_for('companyGallery/add'); ?>" method="post">
        <table  id="tbl" class="company" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px;">
          <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="files" /></td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </form>
      <br />
      <div id="loading" >
        <img alt="loading" src="/images/preloader_transparent.gif" />
      </div>
      <div class="result">
      <table  id="tbl" class="company" cellspacing="0" style="width:250px;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Photo</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php foreach($companyGallery as $x => $gallery): ?>
          <tr id="company<?php echo $gallery->getId(); ?>" class="<?php echo ($x&1) ? 'even':'odd'; ?>">
            <td align="right"><?php echo $gallery->getId(); ?></td>
            <td><a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/uploads/companyGallery/<?php echo $gallery->getImageFull(); ?>" /></a></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
```

in the symfony code below

```
<?php

  class addAction extends sfAction{ 
    private function uploadPhoto($id,$file){
      //echo "test";
      if(!$id){
        $dir = sfConfig::get('app_tempCompGallery_img_dir');
      }else{
        $dir = sfConfig::get('app_companyGallery_dir');
      }

      $full = sfConfig::get('app_companyGallery_full');
      $small = sfConfig::get('app_companyGallery_small');
      $dir = sfConfig::get('app_companyGallery_dir');
      $dir_150 = sfConfig::get('app_companyGallery_dir_150');
      $file['ext'] = getFileExtension($file['name']);
      if(!$id){
        $fileName = uniqid(). '.'.$file['ext'];    
      }else{
        $fileName = $id.'.'.$file['ext'];    
      }
      $imagePath = $dir.$fileName;

      $image_full = encode('CompanyGallery-'.$id).'.'.$fileName;
      $image_small = encode('CompanyGallery-'.$id).'.'.$fileName;
      $image_full_path = $dir.$image_full;
      $image_small_path = $dir_150.$image_small;
      rename($file['tmp_name'],$image_full_path);

      $image = new myImageManipulator($image_full_path);
      $image->resample2($full, $full);
      $image->crop(0, 0, $full, $full);
      $image->save($image_full_path);

      $image = new myImageManipulator($image_full_path);
      $image->resample2($small, $small);
      $image->crop(0, 0, $small, $small);
      $image->save($image_small_path);


      //$companyGallery = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('companyGallery');
      //$this->saveData($companyGallery);
      echo "test345";
      $gallery = Doctrine_Core::getTable('CompanyGallery')->find($id);
      //var_dump($gallery);exit();
      $gallery->setImageFull($image_full);
      $gallery->setImageSmall($image_small);
      $gallery->save();      
    }

    public function execute($request){
      //echo "test macky 123";
      //exit();
      $gallery = new CompanyGallery();
      print_r($gallery);
      $gallery_id = $gallery->getId();
      echo "ASDFAS" .$gallery->getId(); exit();
      $file = $this->request->getFiles();
      print_r($file);
      $file = $file['files'];
      if($file && $file['error'] == 0){
        $this->uploadPhoto($gallery_id,$file);
      }
    }
}
```

as youve notice in the `$gallery = Doctrine_Core::getTable('CompanyGallery')->find($id);`
how do i pass the id in this code? please help..so that it will save to the database the filename

heres my companyTable.class.php in lib/model folder

```
class CompanyGalleryTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    /**
     * Returns an instance of this class.
     *
     * @return object CompanyGalleryTable
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        return Doctrine_Core::getTable('CompanyGallery');
    }

    public function getGalleryList($param=array()){
      $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->from('CompanyGallery c')
         ->orderBy('c.updated_at DESC');

      $pager =  new sfDoctrinePager('CompanyGallery',10);
      $pager->setQuery($q);
      $pager->setPage($param['curPage']);
      $pager->init();
      return $pager;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the Id for insert.

You should just create the object of CompanyGallery class and it will save the the record into the database.

$gallery = new CompanyGallery();

Comment: hi there yes! exactly thats the one im coding here now y is it its empty here $gallery_id = $gallery->getId();
      echo "ASDFAS" .$gallery->getId(); exit(); in the echo $gallery-getId() it is empty..

Comment: hi ive edited the public function execute then add the new companyGallery() but the id is empty....

Comment: Can you just check that records exists in your db or not. just use $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('CompanyGallery')->createQuery();
$companyGallery = $q->execute();

Comment: where will i gonna put that code? in urs? i already have a query in my companyTable.class.php

Comment: hi just edited above i added the companyTable.class.php above

Comment: Did you check how many records exists in your CompanyGallery table?

Comment: how will i gonna do that? ahm i did not check it yet :)

Comment: You can check in your database?

Comment: i check it in my database but ahm no data was inserted

Comment: Thats the reason you are not getting the id...first insert the records in database and then get the id.

Comment: ahh ok but in the public function execute i added the new companyGallery then this code here $class = Doctrine_Core::getTable('CompanyGallery')->find($id);
      $class->setImageFull($image_full);
      $class->setImageSmall($image_small);
      $class->save(); you can find this code in private function uploadPhoto

Comment: In your uploadPhoto function just remove the code  $gallery = Doctrine_Core::getTable('CompanyGallery')->find($id);
      //var_dump($gallery);exit();
      $gallery->setImageFull($image_full);
      $gallery->setImageSmall($image_small);
      $gallery->save();      
    with this    $gallery =  new CompanyGallery();
      //var_dump($gallery);exit();
      $gallery->setImageFull($image_full);
      $gallery->setImageSmall($image_small);
      $gallery->save(); and return  $gallery->getId(); you should the get the id in your execute action.

Comment: it now inserts in my db :)